# JQuery Mobile using simpledialog2 for auth issues

Tags: jquery-mobile, authorization, modal-dialog

I am trying to create a jQuery mobile app which will have an authorisation page, (i.e. a jqm dialog with a text input and a submit button where the user will input their username, this will be checked against a list of users/access rights pulled from Parse and if access is granted  the dialog will be removed and the user can access the app). I realise I a long way from that stage but at the minute I have used the simpledialog2 plugin with Blank mode to create a mockup of how I wanted the dialog to look and I intended to extend this into a fully functioning module.

```
$(document).delegate('#opendialog', 'click', function() {
   $('<div>').simpledialog2({
     mode: 'blank',
     headerText: 'App Auth',
     headerClose: true,
     dialogAllow: true,
     dialogForce: true,
     blankContent : 
       "<p>Please enter your username:<br/></p>"+
       "<form><input/><br/>"+
       "<a data-role='button'>Submit</a></form>"
  })
})
```

When I was trying to extend this code I kept getting errors like "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating ...)" and could not find any cause for them. 
I was wondering if anyone could tell me if I'm approaching this in the correct manner? I tried to create an auth page using the Button w. Input Mode as described on http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos2/blankin.html#/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos2/button.html
but it also didn't work for me. Any guidance would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: Have done some more research and have found that I can create a dialog box for auth using <a href="Auth.html" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog">Open test dialog</a>. However I want to popup this dialog immediately on entry to the application (i.e. so the user cannot access the app without auth), any guidance on how I could do this? Thanks :)

Comment: I have continued researching this with limited success, I have been able to popup a dialog on entry using `$(window).load(function(){
    window.showModalDialog("Auth.html");
  });`

However this only seems to work in IE and not Safari. It also doesn't cover the parent window like using Simpledialog2 does. Any help would be great! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could bind to the `pagebeforechange` event to check if the user is authenticated. If not, you can dynamically create and show an auth dialog:

```
jQuery("body").live("pagebeforechange", function(e, data) {
    if(typeof data.toPage !== 'string')
        return; 
    if(!userIsAuthenticated) {
        showAuthDialog();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

A dynamically generated dialog can be shown like this:

```
function showAuthDialog() {
    var dialog = jQuery('<div data-role="dialog"> <div data-role="content"> <h1>MyAuthDialog</h1> <p>Your auth form here.</p></div> </div>');

    // bind events to auth form here
    // ...

    jQuery.mobile.pageContainer.append(dialog);
    jQuery.mobile.changePage(dialog);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! I have not had the chance to look at this project for some time. But when I do I will be sure try your method. Thanks again :)